# Error on button click of Android App

Tags: android

I have developed an app on Eclipse, but when I click on the buttons of the app, an error message is shown.

The error message is:

```
Unfortunately , database has stopped.
```

`database` is the name of my application.

```
11-01 10:29:51.620: E/memtrack(4150): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
 11-01 10:29:51.620: E/android.os.Debug(4150): failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-01 10:29:51.690: D/AndroidRuntime(4150): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-01 10:29:51.690: D/AndroidRuntime(4150): Shutting down VM
11-01 10:29:51.690: D/dalvikvm(4150): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-01 10:29:51.690: I/AndroidRuntime(4150): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
11-01 10:29:51.700: E/cutils-trace(4150): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: you are supposed to provide supporting details like code snippet or crash log. Otherwise its tough to help you out

Comment: Why you show  error message from your mobile screen?, Add `logcat` `Exception` not your mobile error message.

Comment: add LogCat and post the part of your code that get error .

Comment: not enough information !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a newer version  of the same Application in the target emulator, you will get

```
**Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
failed to load memtrack module: -2**
```

.Try to uninstall the  previous version and try again.